# Is there a minimum height for a meter base / disconnect panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm changing from overhead to underground service. Two inch schedule forty is run from the pole to the house. Question is, is there a minimum height for the meter base / disconnect?

Comment: Who's your electrical utility?  They normally set the minimum and maximum heights for meters

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your utility.

They normally set the rules for the service connection.

Mine has a rather small range for the required height of the center of the installed meter face above ground level (about 1 foot total variation, IIRC. So somehting like 5-6 feet or 5-1/2 to 6-1/2 feet, I don't recall exactly now.) You will also need the working space for that box, IIRC - so 3 feet out, 30 inches wide to include the whole width of the box/panel, area always kept clear and (being outside) smooth/level to stand on and work safely.

Also, you normally need schedule 80 (not 40) for the above-ground parts of the conduit at both ends, if using PVC. You may be able to make them "not exposed to damage" in some other way that suits local inspection or utility, but that's the usual approach, since they are generally exposed to damage and for that, code wants Schedule 80.

Depending on area you may also need expansion (slip) jonts to prevent the conduit breaking with frost motion.

Comment: Does schedule 80 have sweep 90s that have a much larger turn radius that schedule 40? I thought 80 was used for electrical cables and 40 for water flow so 40 does not have large radius 90s? Can Sch 80 sweep 90s be glued to Sch 40 straight pipe?

Comment: I have seen commercial elecrical workers making large radius 90s by heating some large plastic tubing. What material is that?

Comment: Schedule 40 and 80 conduits are compatible. They have the same OD for the fittings to glue to, and the schedule 80 has a thicker wall, so it has a slightly smaller ID for the same size, which can matter for conduit fill calculations. Heat bending PVC conduits is common.  A proper electrical supply can provide large radius sweeps for either material - home centers don't have much of a selection.